# YouTube Video Starts to Buffer again on full screen in Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have integrated YouTube Video in my Android app. Now the problem is when video is turned into full screen (landscape) mode, it starts to buffer again. How to solve this problem?

Below is the whole code I have used.

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    // YouTube player view
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

        // Initializing video player with developer key
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {

            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
            player.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

            // Hiding player controls
            //player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }
}
```

Comment: did u solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add the below lines to your AndroidMenifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode|screenLayout|keyboard">
```

Step 2: activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 3: Create New Class and Named as "Config" you can name as your wish and class must be as below and this  "Config" class for your "YouTubeApi" Key and "Video Id"

```
public class Config {
    public static final String YOUTUBEAPI_KEY = "AIzaSyC5lyioipD0SpJ0UJ5hxz-EDVnO1gZyeI4";
    public static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID = "fhWaJi1Hsfo";
}
```

MainActivity.java file as below:

```
package com.example.tulasi.youtube2;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener  {

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    private boolean mAutoRotation = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAutoRotation = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1;
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube5);
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        if(mAutoRotation) {
            player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                    | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                    | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE
                    | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
        }else {
             player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                     | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                     | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
        }
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
           // String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't abuse bold formatting: it makes your posts harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in your manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
```

inside oncreate add this

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and inside anywhere in activity just add

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Hope this will work

Comment: it makes app full screen without status bar.it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
  android:name="com.example.MainActivity">
```

Put this in your manifest, referencing your main activity.